# SQLAlchemy - How to add dynamic left joins to a query?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have six tables, modeled like the following:

```
+--< B >--C
| 
A
|
+--< D >--E
```

I would like to be able to dynamically query any of these options:

```
A
A, B, C
A, D, E
A, B, C, D E
```

For example, querying all four would look like

```
q = session.query(A, B, C, D, E) \
    .outerjoin(B, A.id == B.a_id).outerjoin(C, C.id == B.c_id)
    .outerjoin(D, A.id == D.a_id).outerjoin(E, E.id == D.e_id)
```

I can append the models to a list and dynamically use them in the `select` clause. However, I cannot figure out how to dynamically attach the joins. Here is what I have so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import outerjoin

models = [A]
joins = []

if foo:
    models.append(B)
    models.append(C)
    joins.append(outerjoin(A, B, A.id == B.a_id))
    joins.append(outerjoin(B, C, C.id == B.c_id))

if bar:
    models.append(D)
    models.append(E)
    joins.append(outerjoin(A, D, A.id == D.d_id))
    joins.append(outerjoin(D, E, E.id == D.e_id))

q = session.query(*models)
# How do I attach my joins list to this query?
```

I have tried the following, which did not work, and even if it did I would presume that the case when `foo` and `bar` are both `False` would leave an empty `FROM` clause.

```
q = q.select_from(*joins)
```

Of course I can get rid of the `joins` list and repeat the `if` conditions after executing `q = session.query(*models)`, like the following, but I would rather perform the conditional logic one time.

```
if foo:
    q = q.outerjoin(B, A.id == B.a_id).outerjoin(C, C.id == B.c_id)

if bar:
    q = q.outerjoin(D, A.id == D.a_id).outerjoin(E, E.id == D.e_id)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `outerjoin` (and other SLQALchemy query methods) modifies a `query` object and returns a new query - which you can  further modify by calling `outerjoin` (or `filter`, etc...)  methods on. 
So, just use a for loop to repeatedly modify your query with an extra `outerjoin` for each set of outerjoin parameters you specify with your conditions. The parameters themselves can be just tuples which you preppend with an `*` just like you do for the models

```
models = [A]
joins = []

if foo:
    models.append(B)
    models.append(C)
    joins.append((A, B, A.id == B.a_id))
    joins.append((B, C, C.id == B.c_id))

if bar:
    models.append(D)
    models.append(E)
    joins.append((A, D, A.id == D.d_id))
    joins.append((D, E, E.id == D.e_id))

q = session.query(*models)
for join_args in joins:
     q = q.outerjoin(*join_args)

# q is now ready to go with all outerjoins specified.
```

Comment: It does not return a new query, it returns a join object

Answer (score 2):

The verified answer by @jsbueno gave me a hint to solve my issue, but it didn't 100% worked for me. Might be a version issue, so providing an almost similar solution that worked for me.

```
models = [A]
joins = []

if foo:
    joins.append((B, A.id == B.a_id))
    joins.append((C, C.id == B.c_id))

if bar:
    joins.append((D, A.id == D.d_id))
    joins.append((E, E.id == D.e_id))

q = session.query(*models)
for join_args in joins:
     q = q.outerjoin(*join_args)

q.all() #This shall give you the required output.
```