# Dynamically add group by clauses to sql alchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a base query(with the necessary columns to query) and I am trying to dynamically add join and group by clauses to the base query using SQL Alchemy ORM
I have already found the operation for adding joins here
[SQLAlchemy - How to add dynamic left joins to a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892088/sqlalchemy-how-to-add-dynamic-left-joins-to-a-query)

from which I have created a function-

```
    add_join_conditions(query,join_conditions):
      for condition in join_conditions:
        query = query.join(*condition)
```

Can someone help me with creating a similar function - add_group_by_columns(query,group_by_columns)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be this

```
 def add_group_by_columns(query, group_by_columns):
   return query.group_by(*group_by_columns)
```

You can then use it like this

```
q = db.session.query(Order.product_id, Order.seller_id, func.count(Order.id)).filter(Order.user_id==12)

q1 = add_group_by_columns(q, [Order.product_category_id, Order.seller_id])

q1.all()
```

Comment: I did try this solution-
However, I get this error :
**NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression**
I am able to apply group by as long as there is only one column to group by.

Comment: Update, I found my error. I was using tuple representation ( ) instead of using list [ ]